# Insert payment parameters into table after PayPal payment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal

I use PayPal-SDK-Rest gem. I have the next def inside of feed.rb(model):

```
def self.paypal_url(return_path)
  values = {
    business: "team@team.com",
    cmd: "_xclick",
    upload: 1,
    return: "#{Rails.application.secrets.app_host}#{return_path}",
    #invoice: id,
    amount: 0.01,
    item_name: "9dt9",
    #item_number: course.id,
    quantity: '1',
    notify_url: "#{Rails.application.secrets.app_host}/hook"
  }
  #"#{Rails.application.secrets.paypal_host}/cgi-bin/webscr?" + values.to_query
  "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?" + values.to_query
end
```

Inside of view file I did put:

```
<%= link_to "Checkout", @feed.paypal_url("http://my_website.com/en") %>
```

For the notify_url I did use the next function in feed_controller:

```
def hook
  params.permit! # Permit all Paypal input params
  #status = params[:payment_status]
  status = params[:st]
  if status == "Completed"
    Transaction.create(:status => params[:st], :transaction_id => params[:tx], :purchased_at => Time.now)
    puts "Data: #{params[:st]} :: #{params[:tx]}"
  else
    puts "NothingHere"
  end
  render nothing: true
end
```

So, it must add my parameters to the table, but it doesn't. What is the problem, who knows? Why it doesn't insert anything into table?

Who can help me with it?

**UPDATE**

In the MGINX log I get:

```
Parameters: {"tx"=>"9BK361abcdefg473M", "st"=>"Completed", "amt"=>"0.01", "cc"=>"USD", "cm"=>"", "item_number"=>"", "locale"=>"en"}
```

Comment: can you update answer with what params you are getting from the `paypal`?

Comment: `puts "Data: #{params[:st]} :: #{params[:tx]}"`, Does this line log any output?

Comment: @usmanali no, it doesn't print this line

Comment: Can you try `Rails.logger.info` instead? My hunch is that it is treating your parameters keys as `strings` not `symbols`

Comment: @usmanali it doesn't help me too =/ Can you help me in chat with it, please? I work about it more than 1 week and nothing =(